# How do I restore three items from a backup made using Heroku PG Backups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I've got a Rails app running on Heroku and installed the free pgbackups addon.

There's three records I'd like to restore from the backup.

According to [Heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#restoring_from_a_backup) when you do a restore, it restores the whole database.

How do I restore just these three records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new database, load the pgbackup into it, and then cherry pick what you want out of it.

Comment: Cool. That's what I thought, just thought there might be a much easier way I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Heroku is using what's referred to as the "-Fc" format for everything, which is described in the [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-pgdump.html) section of the manual as the custom format.  That can't be read by anything but [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-pgrestore.html), so you're limited to what it knows how to do.  You can get pg_restore to only process a single table, which can speed things up if your database is big and you only care about a few records in one table.  But there's no way to only get a few records restored out of there; you'll have to restore the entire table they're in and then dump them back out.