# Heroku PG Backups, how to restore certain records only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backup

I would like to use Heroku PG Backups to able to restore my data in case anything was deleted by mistake. My question is, what if I want to restore just a certain record as well as its associations. Like a student and his grades for example..

I found a similar question: [How do I restore three items from a backup made using Heroku PG Backups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536300/how-do-i-restore-three-items-from-a-backup-made-using-heroku-pg-backups)

However, I don't know what it means to cherry pick items.. How do I do that? .. manually?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I don't know what it means to cherry pick items.. How do I do that? .. manually?

It's a manual process, yes. You can for example use dblink[0] to connect from one DB to the other and pull in the relevant records.

[0] http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dblink.html

Here's a full example on how to use dblink on heroku:

https://gist.github.com/hgmnz/5100682

Comment: oh ok, but how do I do that.. when i read in the documentation it says it needs a connection string.. how do I do that on heroku? How do I connect and pull certain records. Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I so opened a heroku sql console and tried to use dblink_connect to connect to another database, but I get a dblink_connect(unknown,unknown) does not exist. Not sure how i'm supposed to do this..